# C, write in array in a empty space

Tags: c, linux

I have a problem. i'm writting a C code, but my problem is this.

```
int func(const char* path, httpCallback_t handlerFunc) {
    int i;
    int max = 4;
    for (i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        UriArray[i];
        func_ptr[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would add *path and handlerFunc to UriArray[] and func_ptr[] But the constraint is that each time these values ​​are loaded in an empty spac

Regards

Comment: You need to copy path and handlerFunc to UriArray and func_ptr (which I assume are global variables). If you don't copy how will you get the data there? (I did not downvote)

Comment: Kindly rephrase your question.

Comment: thanks. I would add path e handlerFunc to UriArray[] and func_ptr[] But the constraint is that each time these values ​​are loaded in an empty space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UriArray[i];
```

is an expression which "returns" the current value of `UriArray[i]` then throws it away. It's about as useful (without side effects) as the statement:

```
42;
```

If you want to store something in there, you need to assign to it, with something like:

```
UriArray[i] = 314159;
```

Assuming you don't have backing storage for the strings, it's likely to be something like:

```
UriArray[i] = strdup (path);
func_ptr[i] = handlerFunc;
```

But keep in mind that will set all four entries in the arrays to be the same value. That's probably not what you want. It's more likely that you want to append a single entry to the array in which case you'll need to keep a copy of the current size, something like:

```
int size = 0;
#define MAX 4
char *UriArray[MAX];
httpCallback_t func_ptr[MAX];

int func(const char* path, httpCallback_t handlerFunc) {
    if size == MAX) return -1;
    UriArray[size] = strdup (path);
    func_ptr[size++] = handlerFunc;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that *path and handlerFunc are dynamic

Comment: @luigi, it depends on how you want to manage the array. I've given an example of one way, that only allows adds, and fails when the array fills up. There are other ways but, until you specify exactly the behaviour you need, all we can do is show examples.